# Converting Float to Int on certain columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert columns 0 to 4 and 6 to ints from there current float types.

I tried:

```
df[0:4,6].astype(int)
```

but of course this does not work...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10) * 10)
```

[image]

use `np.r_` to get `slc`

```
slc = np.r_[0:4, 6]
df[slc] = df[slc].astype(int)
df
```

or pass a dictionary of types with keys as column names

```
df.astype({c: int for c in slc})
```

[image]

Comment: I get a warning when I try to use any of the apply or astype.
`mapping2['WantedID'] = mapping2['WantedID'].apply(int)`

`__main__:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: `
`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: That is a completely independent issue.  It has to do with the factor that `mapping2` was created in such a way that it is a 'view' of another dataframe.  You can fix that by doing `mapping2 = mapping2.copy()` before you tring assigning to individual columns.  `mapping2 = mapping2.copy()` will make itself a fresh new dataframe that isn't attached to any other dataframe and you'd be free to assign to its columns without any warnings.

Comment: Thanks @pirSquared. it works. Also, it would be great if you could explain why `df[slc].astype(int)` does not work where as `df[slc]=df[slc].astype(int)` works.

Comment: `df[slc].astype(int)` returns a dataframe in which the data type is `int`.  But it does not alter it in place.  You need to assign it back into the same positions.

Comment: @piRSquared how do you assign it back to the same position? For example, I am working on a dataframe `gini` and tried to turn a slice of it into `int` . This is what I did: `pd.to_numeric(gini.iloc[0,4:], downcast = "integer", errors = "coerce")` . The problem is that when I call the dataframe, the changes didn't apply to that slice and I still see those numbers as `float`.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting an error as some of my column values were `NaN` which obviously can not be converted to `int`. So a better approach would be to handle `NaN` before converting the `datatype` and avoid `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`.

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This fills `NaN` with `0` and then converts to the desired `datatype` which is `int` in this case.